# Xpath data extraction from yahoo finance table

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

Want to get yahoo data in google spreadsheet. I don;t want google data from google finance so please don't suggest that. I want yahoo finance data in spreadsheet.

I want data in the following spreadsheet which is editable:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_MQyyaeEtGD0p9l7ncFqyLDWDKsnLNh2XBcH5CiHkF8/edit?usp=sharing

I want only specific column data for just first five days. the link for yahoo data extraction is:

https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/abb.BO/history/?guccounter=1

I have attached image for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2MVo.jpg)

Please help how can I extract data specifically from one column.

I know I will have to use `=transpose(importxml("url,xpath)` but I am not sure about `xpath`.

Comment: The URL redirects to https://in.search.yahoo.com/?fr2=inr, showing "As of August 26th, 2021 Yahoo India will no longer be publishing content. " Removing `in.` the url works, but nowadays it looks that the contents is loaded by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve the latest 5 values of "close" which is yellow range. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In your xpath, `//[@class="Pb(10px) Ovx(a) W(100%)"` cannot be used. If you want to retrieve values from class `Pb(10px) Ovx(a) W(100%)` of div, please modify `"//div[@class='Pb(10px) Ovx(a) W(100%)']"`. This xpath includes the values you want. But it cannot retrieve only the latest 5 values of "close".

  - So I would like to propose `"//tr[position()<6]/td[5]"` as the xpath.

#### Modified formula :

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[position()<6]/td[5]"))
```

- `https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/abb.BO/history/?guccounter=1` is put in "A1".

#### Result :

[image]

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want but is there a work around wherein instead of link In column A1 i can just have the name of the stocks because in links I will have to manually add name of stocks. But I do have the name  of the stocks list. There are many stocks and inserting name in links would take lot of time. Or is there a way where in the link adds names of the stocks after /quote/ instead of doing manually. Many thanks for help

Comment: @study1234 Thank you for your additional information. I could study from your question and comment. Thank you, too.